# requests.post with Python

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm connecting to a login protected API with a Python script here below.

```
import requests

url = 'https://api.json'
header = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
login = ('kjji@snm.com', 'xxxxx')
mnem = 'inputRequests':'{'inputRequests':'[{'function':'GDSP','identifier':'ibm','mnemonic':'IQ_TOTAL_REV'}]}}

    r = requests.post(url, auth=login, data=mnem, headers=header)

    print(r.json())
```

The connection is established but I am getting an error from the API because of the format of the data request.The original format is here below. I cannot find a way to enter this in the mnem here above:

```
inputRequests={inputRequests:
 [
  {function:"xxx",identifier:"xxx",mnemonic:"xxx"},
   ]
}
```

The error given is

```
C:\Users\xxx\Desktop>pie.py
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\pie.py", line 6
    mnem={'inputRequests':'{'inputRequests':'[{'function':'xxx','identifier':'xx','mnemonic':'xxx'}]}}
                                         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am unsure on how to proceed from here. I cannot find anything in the requests documentation that points to how to insert several variables in the data field.

Comment: Sorry that was one of the latest tries. I enclosed everything in '' like below but this is still not working:mnem={‘inputRequests’: {'inputRequests':[{'function':'GDSP','identifier':'ibm','mnemonic':'IQ_TOTAL_REV'}]}}

Comment: Please include what is the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

The `requests` module in Python receive protogenic Python `dict` as the JSON data in post request but not a string. Therefore, you may try to define `mnem` like this:

```
mnem = {
    'inputRequests':[
        {'function':'GDSP',
         'identifier':'ibm',
         'mnemonic':'IQ_TOTAL_REV'
        }
   ]}
```

Comment: This triggers an error from the API: This error means that there is a mistake in the mnemonics. I should mention I am connecting to the api through Postman with the same request and i am getting a result so the input request above is valid.                                    \Users\xxx\Desktop>pie.py {'Errors': 'Error Processing the Request'}

Comment: maybe this:     `mnem = {'inputRequests': {
    'inputRequests':[
        {'function':'GDSP',
         'identifier':'ibm',
         'mnemonic':'IQ_TOTAL_REV'
        }
   ]}}`

Comment: same error as above {'Errors': 'Error Processing the Request'

Comment: This error is received from remote server, something must be wrong with your request. Check if the request body is correct or is there any missing parameters. The `post` request is successfully sent to the API.

Comment: I agree. When using Postman the API responds correctly to the below body.  there are no missing parameters.                                                                        inputRequests={inputRequests:
 [
  {function:"GDSP",identifier:"ibm",mnemonic:"IQ_TOTAL_REV"},
   ]
}

Comment: Can you provide the details of how to use Postman to send the request? What do you fill in the Body option and which format do you choose? It is really weird.

Comment: In Postman i used the raw format and entered the below in the body option: inputRequests={inputRequests:
 [
  {function:"xxx",identifier:"xxx",mnemonic:"xxx"},
   ]
}    I have double checked header and end point and they are exactly the same as i have on Postman. the login and password are also correct

Comment: Try to put the seconde brace into single quotes: `mnem = { 'inputRequest': '{inputRequest: [ { function:"xxx",identifier:"xxx",mnemonic:"xxx"},]}' }`. Be careful with the single quotes and braces.

Answer (score 0):

the `data` parameter should be a dictionary.

therefore to pass the three parameters try using:

```
mnem = {'function':'GDSP','identifier':'ibm','mnemonic':'IQ_TOTAL_REV'}
```

Comment: This triggers an error from the API: This error means that there is a mistake in the mnemonics because i'm missing the 'input request' part  \Users\xxx\Desktop>pie.py
{'Errors': 'Error Processing the Request'}